# Multiple instances of the same component with different config options not rendering properly in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

It seems every time I add a layer of complexity to my Vue app, I break something.

I'm using the vue-flatpickr date/time picker component. I'm using two datepickers and four timepickers on the same page; initially, this worked just fine. I was using the default config for the datepickers, and custom config to make timepickers. The problem appeared when I needed to configure the `dateFormat` of the datepickers.

Suddenly, the timepickers are now datepickers! The weird part is that they're actually ignoring the datepicker config option-- so it's not that they're taking on the inline config, it's more like they're no longer connecting to the right `v-model`.

From my `<template>`:

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <label>Date</label>
   <flat-pickr v-model="date"
              :config="{dateFormat: 'l, F j'}"
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Select date"               
                name="date"></flat-pickr>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col left">
      <label>Time</label>
      <flat-pickr v-model="time"
                :config="config"
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Select time"               
                name="time1"></flat-pickr>
   </div>
</div>
```

From my `<script>`:

```
export default {
  name: 'Contact',
  components: {
      VueSimpleSuggest,
      VueGoogleAutocomplete,
      flatPickr
    },
    data(flatPickr) {
      return {
        date: null
      }
    },
    data(flatPickr) {
      return {
        time: null,
        config: {
          enableTime: true,
          noCalendar: true,
          dateFormat: "H:i",
          time_24hr: true        
        }           
      }
    }
  }
```

I was going to add a codesandbox example, but it's ignoring the inline config altogether for some reason, so it isn't replicating the error.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate what I'm talking about in terms of it filling without the date config options:
[image: screenshot of issue]

Any ideas what could be causing this? Is it a problem with the inline config? I wasn't sure how to do it another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have multiple `data ()` properties? Have you tried this:

```
export default {
  name: 'Contact',
  components: {
    VueSimpleSuggest,
    VueGoogleAutocomplete,
    flatPickr
  },
  data() {
    return {
      date: null,
      time: null,
      dateConfig: {
        altInput: true,
        altFormat: "l, F j",
        dateFormat: "Y-m-d"    
      },
      timeConfig: {
        enableTime: true,
        noCalendar: true,
        dateFormat: "H:i",
        time_24hr: true        
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

And then change this part:

```
<flat-pickr v-model="date"
            :config="dateConfig"
            class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Select date"               
            name="date"></flat-pickr>


...

<flat-pickr v-model="time"
            :config="timeConfig"
            class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Select time"               
            name="time1"></flat-pickr>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same result even with the consolidated `data()`.

Comment: @AmandaHarvey I updated the answer. Add / change / remove the properties inside `timeConfig:{}` and `dateConfig:{}` according to your needs, I just pasted some properties there from the [docs page](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/) of the component you're using just to demonstrate the way you're supposed to specify properties

Comment: Darn, I tried that before, to no avail. Same result. I wonder if something else is interfering.... edit: yup, something else on the page was interfering with it.